# Can FreeForm Pro email a user-entered value?

Tags: solspace-freeform

I have a situation where somebody will submit a form, then somebody else will come back and edit that form. Upon submitting the edit, an email address defined in an open text field in the form will be emailed a notification. Is this possible with FreeForm Pro?

I'm using 4.2.5 with EE 2.7.3, but I'm open to upgrading if a newer release works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently no support for this with Freeform Classic (aka Freeform Pro 4/5/6), nor is there for the new Freeform (aka Freeform Next) editions. However, sometime in the future we might add this type of functionality to Freeform Pro (Next) for EE3/EE4. :)